# Is there a standard visualforce component for a data table with checkboxes?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

When you add new opportunity products, the first page has the table with the list of products and the checkboxes so you can select one or more. Is there a standard visualforce component for this or will I have to create my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard VF component for that, but it is a fairly common use case for which you will find numerous examples on the web.

E.g. http://mycloudexperience.blogspot.nl/2011/03/adding-checkbox-on-pageblocktable.html

Comment: Hmm, I thought that might be the case. I've seen a few DIY examples when looking for an answer but none as short and succinct as the one you posted so thanks :)